# Sort numeric multidimensional array by second column PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have this array:

I want to order it from bigger to smaller sorted by the number in the second column.
I can't get to the second one :(

```
array (size=72)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'Australian SPI 200' (length=18)
      1 => string '-0.055' (length=6)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'CAC 40' (length=6)
      1 => string '-0.007' (length=6)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'DAX' (length=3)
      1 => string '0.007' (length=5)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'EuroStoxx50' (length=11)
      1 => string '0.000' (length=5)
```

Comment: You can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: You can also use http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php for it.

Comment: I don't really know how to use those examples :( i'm kinda new to this

Answer (score 1):

```
function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
    return $a['1'] - $b['1'];
}

$myArray=array (array ( 'Australian SPI 200' , -0.040 ) , array ( 'CAC 40',  -0.006 ) ,array ( 'DAX' ,0.009 ));
usort($myArray, 'sortByOrder');
print_r($myArray);
```

**output**
`Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => DAX [1] => 0.009 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => CAC 40 [1] => -0.006 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Australian SPI 200 [1] => -0.04 ) )`

Comment: This is not working for me when I put the entire array that has like 48x2 columns. I want to order it by the second column, from bigger number to lower number, then print the 10 highest.

Comment: change the columns in function 1 to which you used to short the array
 $a['1'] to  $a[your columms name]

Comment: in your example array you want to sort using key 1 so i used key 1 change in function as per your requirement

Comment: it doens't have a name it has a number. all the time is 0-0-1 1-0-1 2-0-1 3-0-1 4-0-1 and i want to order it by the third number. if 4-0-1 is higher than 3-0-1 then 4-0-1 goes before 3-0-1

Comment: @joshtramposo provide your actual array you  used

Comment: @ankurbhadania how? It's very very long,it has size 72, i can't copy paste it.

Comment: @joshtramposo ok only provide some part of array it only for batter understanding